# "Variable context not set" error with mutate_at, dplyr version >= 0.7

Tags: r, dplyr

This code used to work, as of about May 1 2017 (`dplyr` version 0.5.0). With `dplyr` version 0.7 it fails with `Error: Variable context not set`.  I couldn't find the solution googling around or looking in the [dplyr NEWS file](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md).

This part is fine (setting up the example - could probably be simplified ...)

```
xx <- data.frame(stud_number=1:3,HW1=rep(0,3),HW2=c(NA,1,1),junk=rep(NA,3))
repl_1_NA <- function(x) { return(replace(x,which(x==1),NA)) }
hw1 <- xx %>% select(c(stud_number,starts_with("HW")))
```

Now try to use `mutate_at()`: fails with `dplyr` version >= 0.7.0

```
hw1 %>% mutate_at(starts_with("HW"),repl_1_NA)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When using `starts_with()` as the column selector for `mutate_at`, we now need to wrap it in `vars()`, so the final code line should read

```
hw1 %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("HW")),repl_1_NA)
```

I figured this out by looking at the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729796/replace-na-with-0-using-starts-with/44730173#44730173) and thought I would post it here as a signpost for others ...

Comment: Am I correct that in a dplyr::select or dplyr::distinct statement using multiple calls to dplyr::starts_with, every single dplyr::starts_with must be wrapped in a dplyr::vars? I tried wrapping them all in dplyr::vars (as I would in dplyr::mutate_at) and it didn't work. If this is the case, I am NOT a fan of this change.